# Vaadin: Maven: Not start on production mode. Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json'

Tags: vaadin, maven-3

Vaadin 12.0.4
Maven 3+

I download simple project from Vaadin's official site 
https://vaadin.com/start/latest/simple-ui

In my Vaadin Maven and Jetty project.

In my pom.xml

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode can be activated with either property or profile -->
            <id>production-mode</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>vaadin.productionMode</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It's success build and start in **DEBUG** mode.
Nice.

But I want to start project in **production** mode.

I start from command line:

```
mvn jetty:run -Pproduction-mode
```

or like this:

```
mvn jetty:run -Pproduction-mode -Dvaadin.productionMode=true
```

Project success started. 
But when I try to open web page (`localhost:8080`) I get 
error:

```
[WARNING] unavailable
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json' in the servlet context for 'ES6' browsers. If you are running a dev-mode servlet container in maven e.g. `jetty:run` change it to `jetty:run-exploded`. If you are not compiling frontend resources, include the 'vaadin-maven-plugin' in your build script. Otherwise, you can skip this error either by disabling production mode, or by setting the servlet parameter 'original.frontend.resources=true'.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.readBundleManifest(BundleFilterFactory.java:89)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.createBundleFilterForBrowser(BundleFilterFactory.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.createFilters(BundleFilterFactory.java:70)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.init(VaadinService.java:275)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:201)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:182)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[WARNING] /sw.js
[WARNING] /
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer@a1f5568f==com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says: "If you are running a dev-mode servlet container in maven e.g. `jetty:run` change it to `jetty:run-exploded`."

The reason you must use `jetty:run-exploded` is that the production build output files are placed in appropriate locations inside `/target`, whereas `jetty:run` looks for static resources only in `/src/main/webapp`.