# Runnable jar production mode: Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json'

Tags: maven, vaadin, jetty-9

In my Kotlin Jetty  project I build by maven.
I need to start applcation in production mode.
(from here https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html)
As result in my pom.xml

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production-mode</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
</profile>
```

So to start in production mode by Maven I use command:

```
mvn jetty:run-exploded -Pproduction-mode
```

and my web application start in **production mode**.
Nice.

But I alson need to create executable jar (or war) to start my web application from console.
So as result I use maven's pluggin "`maven-shade-plugin`"
So in my pom.xml I add:

```
plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.myproject.AppStarterKt</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

and create jar in production mode:

```
mvn verify -Pproduction-mode
```

as result I get standalone (runnable) jar that content all dependencies. Nice.

But when I want to start standalone jar in PRODUCTION MODE like this:

```
java -Dvaadin.productionMode=true -jar myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But I get error:

```
[qtp1495242910-15] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.ROOT - unavailable
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json' in the servlet context for 'ES6' browsers. If you are running a dev-mode servlet container in maven e.g. `jetty:run` change it to `jetty:run-exploded`. If you are not compiling frontend resources, include the 'vaadin-maven-plugin' in your build script. Otherwise, you can skip this error either by disabling production mode, or by setting the servlet parameter 'original.frontend.resources=true'.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.readBundleManifest(BundleFilterFactory.java:89)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.createBundleFilterForBrowser(BundleFilterFactory.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.createFilters(BundleFilterFactory.java:70)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.init(VaadinService.java:275)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:201)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:182)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[qtp1495242910-15] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /booking-v2
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer@a1f5568f==com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json' in the servlet context for 'ES6' browsers. If you are running a dev-mode servlet container in maven e.g. `jetty:run` change it to `jetty:run-exploded`. If you are not compiling frontend resources, include the 'vaadin-maven-plugin' in your build script. Otherwise, you can skip this error either by disabling production mode, or by setting the servlet parameter 'original.frontend.resources=true'.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.readBundleManifest(BundleFilterFactory.java:89)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.createBundleFilterForBrowser(BundleFilterFactory.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.BundleFilterFactory.createFilters(BundleFilterFactory.java:70)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.init(VaadinService.java:275)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:201)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:182)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:672)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vaadin: Maven: Not start on production mode. Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159787/vaadin-maven-not-start-on-production-mode-failed-to-find-the-bundle-manifest)

Comment: No duplicate. I want to start from console (without maven). Only as standalone jar.

Comment: So the answer from the linked question solved your question there? Then you may mark the answer there as accepted first.

Comment: It's solved problem when run application by MAVEN. But from command line by java - jar xxx it's not help me.

Answer (score 1):

During a production build, `vaadin-maven-plugin` creates a production bundle and puts the resulting files in `/target/<nameAndVersion>/` so that the files would be available as static resources when deployed as a `.war`. When packaging as a jar file and embedding a servlet container, you need to configure the plugin to put those files in some other location instead.

What location to use be depends on how the embedded servlet container is configured. One quite popular choice is to use `META-INF/resources`. To make it work in this way, you can set the `transpileOutputDirectory` configuration parameter for the plugin to `${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/resources`.

Comment: A also created a ticket about using a more sensible default configuration: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5293